# Left joining one QuerySet to another

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

Is it possible to `LEFT JOIN` one `QuerySet` to another?  I know it's possible to `INNER JOIN` two, as follows:

`QuerySet1.filter(foreign_key__in=QuerySet2)`

Is there any way to achieve a similar effect but with a `LEFT` rather than `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an inner join. It's a sub-select query, which gives you all the results of queryset1 which have their FK in queryset 2 - but it's not a join, as at the end you only have the elements from the Q1 table, not those in q2.

The only way to do a real join - ie get elements from both tables in one query - is to use `select_related`. What happens here is that the foreign key relationship in table1 are prepopulated with the result of the join. So, by default this is a left join, not an inner one, as you get the elements of table1 whether or not there are any matches in table2.

You could combine the two techniques to simulate an inner join: `QuerySet1.select_related().filter(foreign_key__in=QuerySet2)` but I'm not sure if the query creator is clever enough to combine those into a single join, or whether it will do a join + a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join means that you want all results from first query set, then, response to your answer is:

```
QuerySet1.all()
```

Remember that you can select related table properties with [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
QuerySet1.select_related('model2__model3__some_property')
```

This will generate a left join foreign key to model2 allow nulls.